# How do I properly set up a django project in OSx?

Tags: python, django, macos, path

I  have a background in programming with python but I really would like to start playing around with django but I have had difficulty setting up a project.

I know that I have django installed but the command django-admin is not recognized. I believe this has something to do with the way my path is set up. I still feel clumsy about setting up correct paths, so a clear explanation of this would be greatly appreciated.

I also understand that it is advisable to set everything up within a virtual environment. I believe that I have pip installed which should enable virtualenv to be recognized, unfortunately the virtualenv command is also not recognized. I feel like I'm missing something very basic. Any help on setting up these basics would be very greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do anything with paths at all, other than setting up a virtualenv. If you have pip, you can install virtualenv with `sudo pip install virtualenv` (and note that this is the last thing you should install with `sudo pip`; everything else after that should be inside an activated virtualenv).

Comment: I get a message when using that command that says that the directory is not owned by the current user and te cache has been disabled. It also suggests using something called an -H flag if im using sudo.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Please show the exact command you used and the full error you got (as an edit to the question).

Comment: Edit your question, not my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use virtualenv - look here:
[Python - Virtualenv , python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416005/python-virtualenv-python-3/28298765#28298765)

Then after you source the env you simply do a `pip install Django`.